# SQL Server merge with dates

Tags: c#, sql-server

I currently have a table with a column named Date and it's default values is `getdate()`. I am using a `merge` statement and I only want it to update if the file is uploaded on the same date. If it's a different date I want to insert a new row. my question is, will this work:

```
var sqlCommand = string.Format(@"
  MERGE [HEWreport] AS target USING (
    select @Property_ID as Property_ID, @val as {0}
  ) AS source ON (
    target.Date = getdate()
  ) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET {0}= source.{0} 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Property_ID, {0}) 
    VALUES (source.Property_ID, source.{0});", column);
```

Comment: Have you tested this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to validate the syntax without sample data.  I do believe that will work for you but you want to match on more than date, I am guessing property_id?

Currently your query will update all records with todays date.

EDIT:
Use `Convert(Date, target.Date) = Convert(Date, getdate())`

Comment: Yes, it will match with property_id as well. I took it out of this pasting of my code because i didn't want to over complicate my question. Basically, I have two files coming in every day. So I want it to make a new row when the property's are different and when the day is different. The problem I am having is that even though my day is the same, it is still making new rows for the same one property.

Comment: Ahh it must be that getdate returns time as well.  I will edit.